# Angular two way binding to get total from input fields

Tags: angular, typescript

Below I have 5 input field which are rent , cam , security and support and estimated revenue , now how do we bind those input fields to get each value and show and assign the total of the 5 fields to the total rent field ?

Everytime the value changes on for example on rent , cam etc. it should update the total value on the total montly rent field

For example if rent field value is 2 , cam is 1 , security is 1 , support is 1 and estimated revenue is 1  then the value of total monthly rent is 6. And If I change any of the value it should update the total.

Anyone has an idea , would be muchly appreciated.

[image]

#ts code

```
class DealPLSFormFields {
  dealName:string;
  dealSummary:string;
  dealPartner:string;
  startDate: string;
  endDate: string;
  rent: number;
  cam:number;
  totalBrokerCommission: number;
  supportServicesFee: number;
  estimatedOtherRevenue;
  descriptionOfOtherRevenue: string;
  totalMonthlyRentAndFees : number;
  buildOutCostReimbursement: number;
  dealId: number;
  securityMonitoring: any;

  constructor(){
    this.dealName = null;
    this.dealSummary = null;
  }
}

dealPLSFormFields: DealPLSFormFields;
  ngOnInit(): void {   
    this.dealPLSFormFields = new DealPLSFormFields();
   
  }
```

#html code

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center" >
            <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="w-49per">
                <mat-label>Rent (Monthly)</mat-label>
                <input 
                  matInput
                  [(ngModel)]="dealPLSFormFields.rent"
                  [required]="isExistingDeal">
              </mat-form-field>
              <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="w-49per">
                <mat-label>CAM (Monthly)</mat-label>
                <input 
                  matInput
                  [(ngModel)]="dealPLSFormFields.cam"
                  [required]="isExistingDeal">
              </mat-form-field>
          </div>
          <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center" >
            <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="w-49per">
                <mat-label>Security Monitoring (Monthly)</mat-label>
                <input 
                  matInput
                  [(ngModel)]="dealPLSFormFields.securityMonitoring"
                  [required]="isExistingDeal">
              </mat-form-field>
              <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="w-49per">
                <mat-label>Support Services Fee (Monthly)</mat-label>
                <input 
                  matInput
                  [(ngModel)]="dealPLSFormFields.supportServicesFee"
                  [required]="isExistingDeal">
              </mat-form-field>
          </div>
          <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
            <mat-label>Estimated Other Revenue (e.g, percentage rent, referral fees)</mat-label>
            <input 
              matInput
              [(ngModel)]="dealPLSFormFields.estimatedOtherRevenue"
              [required]="isExistingDeal">
          </mat-form-field>
          <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
            <mat-label>Description of Other Revenue</mat-label>
            <input 
              matInput
              [(ngModel)]="dealPLSFormFields.descriptionOfOtherRevenue"
              [required]="isExistingDeal">
          </mat-form-field>
          <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
            <mat-label>Total Monthly Rent and Fees</mat-label>
            <input 
              matInput
              [(ngModel)]="dealPLSFormFields.totalMonthlyRentAndFees"
              [required]="isExistingDeal">
          </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: You should use reactive form module and subscribe to the formGroup changes to do such calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said, best is to use the reactive forms for such use cases, but if you are not able to and want to go ahead with current implementation, do the following changes:

Add a keyup listener to all your input element that would perform the calculation:

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center" >
<mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="w-49per">
    <mat-label>Rent (Monthly)</mat-label>
    <input 
      matInput
      (keyup) = "calc()"
      [(ngModel)]="dealPLSFormFields.rent"
      [required]="isExistingDeal">
    
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="w-49per">
    <mat-label>CAM (Monthly)</mat-label>
    <input 
      matInput
      (keyup) = "calc()"
      [(ngModel)]="dealPLSFormFields.cam"
      [required]="isExistingDeal">
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center" >
<mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="w-49per">
    <mat-label>Security Monitoring (Monthly)</mat-label>
    <input 
      matInput
      (keyup) = "calc()"
      [(ngModel)]="dealPLSFormFields.securityMonitoring"
      [required]="isExistingDeal">
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="w-49per">
    <mat-label>Support Services Fee (Monthly)</mat-label>
    <input 
      matInput
      (keyup) = "calc()"
      [(ngModel)]="dealPLSFormFields.supportServicesFee"
      [required]="isExistingDeal">
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
<mat-label>Estimated Other Revenue (e.g, percentage rent, referral fees)</mat-label>
<input 
  matInput
  (keyup) = "calc()"
  [(ngModel)]="dealPLSFormFields.estimatedOtherRevenue"
  [required]="isExistingDeal">
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
<mat-label>Description of Other Revenue</mat-label>
<input 
  matInput
  (keyup) = "calc()"
  [(ngModel)]="dealPLSFormFields.descriptionOfOtherRevenue"
  [required]="isExistingDeal">
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
<mat-label>Total Monthly Rent and Fees</mat-label>
<input 
  matInput
  [(ngModel)]="dealPLSFormFields.totalMonthlyRentAndFees"
  [required]="isExistingDeal">
</mat-form-field>
```

next, in your component:

```
 calc() {
    const rent = this.dealPLSFormFields.rent ? this.dealPLSFormFields.rent : 0;
    const cam = this.dealPLSFormFields.cam ? this.dealPLSFormFields?.cam : 0;
    this.dealPLSFormFields.totalMonthlyRentAndFees = +rent + +cam;
  }
```

Check this stackblitz for working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-material-starter-5ceexh?file=src/app/app.module.ts

Answer (score 2):

If you need the `totalMonthlyRentAndFees` field to be changed to hold the total value, to be able to send it later to the server, you can achieve that by listening to the other fields changes (using `ngModelChange`) and calculating the `totalMonthlyRentAndFees` based on them.

You can change your code to be like the following:

```js
model = {
  x: 1,
  y: 2,
  total: 3,
};

onChange() {
  this.model.total = Number(this.model.x) + Number(this.model.y);
}
```

```html
<label>X</label>
<input [(ngModel)]="model.x" (ngModelChange)="onChange()" />

<label>Y</label>
<input [(ngModel)]="model.y" (ngModelChange)="onChange()" />

<label>Total</label>
<input [ngModel]="model.total" />
```

Here's a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gbphbq) demo.

**Note:** You can bind the `total` input to a property `getter` and assign the value within it to the total property, then return it.

However, this will cause the property `getter` to be calculated on each Angular change detection.

Comment: Hi Sir @Amer , do you have idea with this one ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69287796/excel-has-diffrent-result-than-js-computation Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using a template driven form. To do this quite simply you can use a Typescript getter.

```
get mySum() {
  return this.dealPLSFormFields.rent + this.dealPLSFormFields.cam + etc
}
```

Now you can access the value of this calculation as follows:

ts:

```
console.log(this.mySum)
```

html:

```
{{ mySum }}
```

You could also feed it into a form field using one way binding:

```
[ngModel]="mySum"
```

and make the form field readonly

Alternatively, you could switch to a reactive form and use valueChanges to do the calculation:

```
this.reactiveForm.valueChanges.subscribe(x => {
  // do calculation here
})
```

The reactive form approach is more programmatic and less expensive since TypeScript getters are constantly being executed. However, since your calculation is quite lightweight you should be fine sticking with a template driven form.